# how to send data through URL in Google app Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to send data of my spreadsheet to an other server, I've tried this.I am not getting error but its not working too.

I tried lots of things but no joy.

```js
var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Send to PLM", functionName: "email"} ];
  ss.addMenu("MyMenu", menuEntries);
}

function email() {
 //Browser.msgBox("Hello World");
  //var url = "http://********/noetic_Data/AddDataToAras?data="; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var columns = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = rows.getNumColumns();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= numColumns - 1; j++) {
      var row = values[i][j];
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(numRows+"::"+numColumns);
  var excelData = "";
  for(var k=0;k<values.length;k++)
  {
    if(excelData == "")
    {
     excelData = values[k]; 
    }
    else
    {
      excelData = excelData +"|"+ values[k]; 
    }
  }
  
   Browser.msgBox(excelData) ;
  return excelData;
   //var url = "http://*****/noetic_Data/AddDataToAras?data="+excelData; 

   var response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest("http://******/noetic_Data/AddDataToArasdata=", excelData)
   //fetch("******/noetic_Data/AddDataToAras?data=", excelData);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   
 // s = s+excelData;
 //return s;

}
```

Comment: Not enough info in this question yet, so you need to do some more work. `getRequest()` will show what the `fetch` would look like IF it was sent - but you haven't shown what you're getting. Your `options` value is a string, but should be an object with specific names properties - the string _is_ an object, everything in JavaScript is, it's just missing properties that would end up in the `GET` request.  Set `muteHttpExceptions : true` in the options for `fetch` so you can capture the response and examine it.

Comment: thanks Rohil for reaching me, but i got the solution...

Comment: If you have a solution that could help others, you can answer your own question.

Comment: yeah sure,  will do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


function onOpen() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var columns = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = rows.getNumColumns();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= numColumns - 1; j++) {
      var row = values[i][j];
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1);
    }
  }
  var excelData = "";
  for(var k=0;k<values.length;k++)
  {
    if(excelData == "")
    {
     excelData = values[k]; 
    }
    else
    {
      excelData = excelData +"|"+ values[k]; 
    }
  }
  //Bowser.msgBox(excelData) ;     //***to view data on browser****
  

  var shUi = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Custom functions');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().add(app.createHTML('Click the button bellow to send data to PLM')
  .setStyleAttribute('padding','10px'));
  var grid = app.createGrid(1,2).setWidth('200');
  var b1 = app.createButton("send to PLM");
  var link = app.createAnchor('XXXXX',"http://***.**.*.***/noetic_Data/AddDataToAras?data="+excelData).setStyleAttributes({'zIndex':'1' , 'position':'fixed' , 'top':'45' , 'left':'20', 'color':'transparent' }).setTitle('proceed in a new tab');
  var G1 = app.createVerticalPanel().add(b1).add(link);
   grid.setWidget(0,0,G1);
  app.add(panel).add(grid)
  shUi.showSidebar(app);
 }
```

Comment: Good... but better if it included an explanation of what the necessary change was.